# Graph Not Cooperating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a crosshair type of graph that you can find here:

https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/4b8ede8e1b45ce1abf55f981a261a8d1

I apologize that it doesn't fit into the block. Bonus points for explaining how to correct that!

Once you click on the full screen view (or zoom out a little), you will see the real problem. The crosshairs doesn't follow the mouse moves. The code is not super efficient, I just spliced 2 graphs together frankenstein style (hey its halloween soon) so that's why it is so many lines long. Even though my X and Y axis are both in linear scales, I kept the labels of the template which was a time dimensional x axis, hence d.date.

I did manage to get what you see as index.html in the above link working on about four separate occasions. However, this time around, it didn't work. The mouse move fails, and as a result the crosshair is kind of stuck in one place. My guess is it has something to do with the way the data is parsed? Since it seems to be an error particular to this dataset, but I've been wrong before. Please leave your hunches. I'm out of ideas.

Last thing I'll add is dev tools gives me an error that says 'cannot read property 'date' of undefined' with regards to the mousemove function.

```
          function mousemove() {
          var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
              i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
              d0 = data[i - 1],
              d1 = data[i],
              d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

I'm not sure that's actually the TRUE culprit though, I've had this error before and the graph work fine. Thought I'd play it safe and share the error, in case it helps.